# Rendering Jinja2 inheritance

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2

I want to use the concept of inheritance in jinja2 to separate different parts of the configuration into multiple separate child templates.

Ultimately, make it work for more complex hierarchy, something like:

```
parent.jj2
  |_child1.jj2
  |   |_child11.jj2
  |   |
  |   |_child12.jj2
  |
  |_child2.jj2
      |_child21.jj2
      |
      |_child22.jj2
```

In this example I use only 2 child templates:

**parent.jj2 template:**

```
## Main file header
{% block child1 %}{% endblock %}
##
{% block child2 %}{% endblock %}
## Main file tail
```

**child1.jj2 template:**

```
{% extends "parent.jj2" %}
{% block child1 %}
{% for i in list %}
child1 line {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**child2.jj2 template:**

```
{% extends "parent.jj2" %}
{% block child2 %}
{% for i in list %}
child2 line {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I use the following render, where child template are rendered separately, but it doesn't produce the desired result:

**Used jinja2 Loader:**

```
list1 = \
    [1,2,3]

list2 = \
    ['a','b','c']

loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd())
jenv = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader, trim_blocks=True,lstrip_blocks=True)

template = jenv.get_template('child1.jj2')
print template.render(list=list1)

template = jenv.get_template('child2.jj2')
print template.render(list=list2)
```

How to call the render in a such way that I have the main template rendered with the child blocks in a single file?

**Desired result:**

```
## Main file header
child line1 1
child line1 2
child line1 3
##
child line1 a
child line1 b
child line1 c
## Main file tail
```

**Current outcome:**

```
## Main file header
child line1 1
child line1 2
child line1 3
##
## Main file tail

## Main file header
##
child line1 a
child line1 b
child line1 c
## Main file tail
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result the other way around using **include**.

**Rendering the parent template** which **includes all children templates**

**parent.jj2:**

```
#Main file header
{% include "child1.jj2" %}
##
{% include "child2.jj2" %}
#Main file tail
```

**child1.jj2**

```
{% block peceinterfaces %}
{% for i in list[0] %}
child1 line1 {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**child2.jj2:**

```
{% block pepinterfaces %}
{% for i in list[1] %}
child2 line1 {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Rendering the parent template:

```
list1 = \
    [1,2,3]

list2 = \
    ['a','b','c']

loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd())
jenv = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader, trim_blocks=True,lstrip_blocks=True)

template = jenv.get_template('parent.jj2')
print template.render(list=[list1,list2])
```

**The result:**

```
#Main file header
child1 line1 1
child1 line1 2
child1 line1 3
##
child2 line1 a
child2 line1 b
child2 line1 c
#Main file tail
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extends in top of the child templates

```
{% extends "child1.jj2l" %}
```

Comment: #Garesh-shyara, that's the initial condition which doesn't produce the desired outcome.